# Messagebox will not stop showing

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to write this code so that when click start Obj from `"FORM1"` will call this method to use and enable `timer1`.

When I click the start button a dog picture will start to move to right side until reach `X= 620` then it will show messagebox `" win"`

However the message box keeps showing and doesn't stop after dogpic reach goal-line

```
class dog
{
    public int startpost;
    public int TrackLenght = 620;
    public PictureBox dogpic = null;
    public int Location = 0;
    public Random random=new Random();

    public void ResetStart()
    { 
        dogpic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, startpost);
    }

    public bool testrun()
    {
        Point p = dogpic.Location;

        if (p.X < TrackLenght)
        {
            int distance = random.Next(5);

            p.X = p.X + distance;
            dogpic.Location = p;
            Location = dogpic.Location.X;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dogpic.Name + " win");

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `timer`? Just stop it.

Comment: my timer_Tick is in FORM1 i leave it with

timer.Enabled=true;

Comment: you need to add the code for `timer_tick`, timer has a method called `Stop()` I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//suppose dog1 is an instance of your dog class
//here is the Tick event handler of your timer1
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    timer1.Enable = !dog1.testrun();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reseting  p.X after you win.

Dont see it your code but I think you should do something like this:

```
public bool testrun()
    {

        Point p = dogpic.Location;

        if (p.X < TrackLenght)
        {
            int distance = random.Next(5);

            p.X = p.X + distance;
            dogpic.Location = p;
            Location = dogpic.Location.X;
           return false;
        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show(dogpic.Name + " win");
            ResetStart()
            return true;
        }}}
```

Answer (score 1):

On click of button you should call ResetStart() function which will enable timer and do your work and on reaching end point it should disable timer.

```
class dog
{
    public int startpost;
    public int TrackLenght = 620;
    public PictureBox dogpic = null;
    public int Location = 0;
    public Random random=new Random();

    public void ResetStart()
    { 
        dogpic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, startpost);
        timer.Enabled=true;
    }

    public bool testrun()
    {
        Point p = dogpic.Location;

        if (p.X < TrackLenght)
        {
            int distance = random.Next(5);

            p.X = p.X + distance;
            dogpic.Location = p;
            Location = dogpic.Location.X;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dogpic.Name + " win");
            timer.Enabled=false;    
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer.

```
timer.Interval=5000;
timer.Enabled=true;
MessageBox.Show(dogpic.Name + " win");
```

You can associate it with the tck event.

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs evt) {
    timer.Enabled=false;
}
```

Comment: I didnt get your point. Is my answer wrong for you?? I guess it will work. I definitely done deserve your downvote :(

Comment: Its OK...you can only vote once for a question or answer but if my answer really helped you. You can accept it as answer!!! :)

Comment: @eathapeking Can't you just click the downvote button again to cancel it?

Comment: @Bridge:- Thanks a lot. Till now I was thinking what was wrong in the answer. Was the first one to answer but got the -1  :(

Comment: if i click donw vote it will be -2 at first i try to cancle but it out of time

Comment: Don't be sorry just click that downvote button again or a upvote button to nullify its effect...:-)

Comment: answer is not wrong but i click it wrong my bad i but i think i didn't click wrong

all give up for all other already but maybe i click to fast :(

Comment: OK...No issues...I thought you could have acccpted my answer so that it could have nullified the downvote!!! :)

Comment: i'm not the who click downvote for you it is someone else :D  cause if i cancle it it will -1 :)

Comment: You can do it like:- timer.Interval=5000;
MessageBox.Show(dogpic.Name + " win"); timer.Enabled=true; Just make this change in your present code!!!